# How to add PageView webpart?

Tags: web-part

This is not working....

```
SPLimitedWebPartManager webpartManager = webPartPage.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
PageViewerWebPart pvwp = new PageViewerWebPart();
pvwp.Title = "My Page View WP";
webpartManager.AddWebPart(pvwp, "TOP", 0);
```

Comment: WebPartPage class does not have GetLimitedWebPartManager method. From where do you get your `webPartPage` object?

Comment: SPFile also has a GetLimitedWebPartManager method, so I'm assuming webPartPage is the aspx page.

Comment: @Laurie: you are correct . SPFile webPartPage = "mypage.aspx";

Comment: Did you mean `SPFile webPartPage = web.GetFile("mypage.aspx")`? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Looks like you may be missing a call to [SPLimitedWebPartManager.SaveChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.splimitedwebpartmanager.savechanges.aspx).</strike> As @omlin points out, this isn't actually necessary.

Here is the code I'm using which is working fine:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://servername/sites/test/"))
{
    SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
    SPFile webPartPage = web.GetFile("Pages/Default.aspx");
    SPLimitedWebPartManager webPartManager = webPartPage.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
    PageViewerWebPart pvwp = new PageViewerWebPart();
    pvwp.Title = "My Page Viewer Web Part";
    webPartManager.AddWebPart(pvwp, "TOP", 0);

    // not actually needed
    //webPartManager.SaveChanges(pvwp);
}
```

Things to check:

- Does your page need to be checked out? (Check `webPartPage.CheckOutStatus`)
- Do you have permission?
- Are you receiving an error?

Reference

- [Add webpart on sharepoint page programmatically](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/1bc7212c-385d-4a89-9b7e-9d37ee762017)

Comment: Have just tested: you don't need to call SaveChanges when adding a new webpart...

Comment: @omlin: so what am I missing. Still not working for me. Can you possibly post your code? Thanks

Comment: @Roxanne, I have code similar to yours, and it works fine :( I tested with both SPFile.GetLimitedWebPartManager and SPWeb.GetLimitedWebPartManager - and even if you're providing non-existant webpart zone, it works (adds the webpart to the end of last webpart zone on the page).

Comment: Hmm.. you are right as always @omlin. :)  The only time I can get it to fail is if the page isn't checked out.

Comment: That could be the reason:) I only have SharePoint Foundation at home, and cannot test publishing pages.

Comment: @It's publishing page. I am checking out then adding wp then checking back in. The page layout is custom so I change the web part zone to LeftColumnZone per layout definition. Still not poping up.

Comment: @ME:  I instantiate myself with SPFool. My page name is customerPage.aspx not customer page.aspx. It should be fixed. LOL

Comment: Shall I delete the question then?

Comment: @Kit: hmm well, i would leave it for good piece of code that's been reviewed and baptized by pros like you omlin and everyone.